# How to determine the number of characters read by unformatted input functions?

Tags: c++, istream

The various unformatted input functions on `std::istream` (well, really, `std::basic_istream`) like `read()`, `readsome()`, `getline()`, and `ignore()` all return a stream. When processing the results it is often important to know how many character were actually read. Relying on a null character in the string obviously doesn't work for binary files or `ignore()` which doesn't even involve any string, i.e., something like `strlen()` is entirely out of question.

How can the number of characters which were read by the last unformatted input operation using an `std::istream`, or more generally, `std::basic_istream`, be determined?

Comment: You've mentioned `std::istream::gcount` in your recent answer, what are your concerns?

Comment: @LogicStuff: my recent answer was on `readsome()` which does include the answer but the question is unlikely to be found by anybody using `std::istream::getline()` or `std::istream::read()` while this question has more hope of being found when someone looks determining the number of characters being read.

Comment: @LogicStuff: I expect this to be an FAQ-style question. I don't think Dietmar would need SO to actually answer any questions about C++ :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`gcount()` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) of the `basic_istream` base class to retrieve the count of characters obtained by the last unformatted input operation.